# Font glitch in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 on Fedora 23

Tags: intellij-idea

In the project overview module names seem to be truncated and the last character in the name is missing or partly missing. This problem seem to have occurred when upgrading from version 15 to version 2016.1.

Is there a setting I shoud look into or is there a font issue on my system?

[screenshot of the project overview with module names (partly) missing last character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXruf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a bug registered at JetBrains for this problem:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152454